# Phonegap InAppBrowser exit not stopping video playback

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

When using PhoneGap's `InAppBrowser` I am loading a page with a video. If I play that video and close the `InAppBrowser` the video playback continues. I have searched high and low for an answer to this issue. How can I stop the playback or remove the connection when closing the `InAppBrowser`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. What you want to do, is set target from `_blank` to `_self` that will cause it to stop playback when you hit the back button.

`var ref = window.open(url, '_self', options);`

[window.open](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#window.open)

Comment: Whilst this appears to work, what it does is simply replace your HTML app with the page you loaded. When you navigate back you reload your HTML app again. That may be a work-around in some cases, but it is not a fix for the underlying problem.